# Rules for creative writing?

Tags: creative-writing

What makes a good 'story' - a short creative writing prompt that has to be influenced by a stimulus (the topic being 'discovery')?

Any general rules, apart from the fact that it has to be third person.

Comment: Are you asking about the rules for the story or the prompt?

Comment: I'm sorry; this is far too broad. There are a million rules, guidelines and variations when it comes to writing. Try a good book on creative writing for the basics.

Answer (score 1):

**1) It does not to have to be in third person** : I don’t know if it was part of your assigment to write it in third person, but to make good story, you do not have to write it in third person. Third person does not imply that it will be good story.

**2) Make it unusual:** Few ideas on "discovery" topic which may make good story:

- Dog puppy discovering its neighbourhood for the first time
- Young couple discovering their bodies for first time (quite "problematic" topic, especially if you are still on school)
- Seeing usual object (like cup of tea) by looking at it as if you see it for the first time

**3) Tell a story** You can describe Egypt pyramids the way it will make everyone sleepy. Or you can tell a story about mighty Pharaoh, who just deceased. And people build him tomb deserving the greatness of his actions.

**4) Write about something you know** While writing story about discovering India might sound cool for me (being from Europe), but telling something "spicy" about my own neighbourhood will make more plausible story, without any clichés.

**5) Write something funny or interesting at the end.** Especially if it is short story. Such story should have good point. And good story has great point. Will you guess the stories from the points?:

- It was Earth the whole time!
- The main villain is actually a father of main hero!
- He was dead the whole time!
- The detective is actually the killer!

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules.

Readers are different and enjoy different things. Every rule will result in a text that is uninteresting for someone.

If you find your text interesting, others will, too.

---

Note:

You did not ask how to write stories that sell or stories that are reviewed well. You asked what makes a good story. I answered that question. There is no agreement on what is "good".

Comment: This answer is giving me chills. While it is true, I still cannot get my head around it. Because to me it kinda suggests that there are no "bad" stories...

Comment: There are no bad stories. Only stories that seem bad to specific people.